# Why sorted data as input is required for most of STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

While using STL algorithms in C++, I found lot of methods like `std::merge`, `std::inplace_merge`, `std::set_union`, `std::upper_bound`, `std::lower-bound` etc... takes only sorted data as input.

It makes sense that, on sorted data these algorithms will give faster results, but why can't they handle unsorted data too ? Why most of the algorithms are designed with data dependencies like these ?.

Comment: That's because it would require checking if a sequence is sorted and that would change complexity of algorithms like `std::lower_bound` from O(log n) to O(n). Also there's nothing stopping you from sorting beforehand if you aren't sure.

Comment: These are very common algorithms that should not have to waste time checking if the data is sorted before continuing. You can always make a wrapper function that pre-sorts the data before calling the algorithm. I suppose you could have a debug version of the algorithms that throws an exception if the data is not sorted before-hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It makes sense that, on sorted data these algorithms will give faster results, but why can't they handle unsorted data too ? Why most of the algorithms are designed with data dependencies like these ?.

For the algorithms where "It makes sense" to have data sorted, the developer should know whether that will be the case or not, and can easily sort the input if needed.  The algos could check whether the data's sorted themselves first, but that would waste time when unnecessary.  For example, `upper_bound` can be O(logN) on pre-sorted input, while checking for sorting would be O(N).  Keep in mind too that in general the algos have nowhere to store status saying *"I checked once and the data was sorted"* (and how could they know how long that will hold without understanding what threads exist, how they use locks etc), so they'd have to do it *for each call* on the data.

Further, some of the algorithms you mention - e.g. [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) - can be used on [InputIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), which means you can process input that can only be read once, such as from a keyboard where it's made available momentarily but not automatically persisted anywhere for you to revisit, so having an extra pass to check whether the values someones typing are already sorted is impractical.

Comment: *For the algorithms where "It makes sense" to have data sorted, the developer should know whether that will be the case or not, and can easily sort the input if needed.* This is not correct. In such case the data **has to be in sorted form initially** and developer should not be required to sort the data for the very purpose of using an algorithm.  Because if data is not sorted then sorting it would cost atleast O(nLogn). By sorting the data and then using `lower-bound` would cost O(nLogn) instead of O(n) if directly the unsorted data is used.

Comment: @sameerkn: *"should not be required to sort the data for the very purpose of using an algorithm [,b]ecause if data is not sorted then sorting it would cost atleast O(nLogn)."* - your reasoning is simply wrong.  It's quite common to be prepared to take the hit to sort something once so that you can apply alogorithms against it quickly multiple times thereafter (e.g. sorting a `vector` then doing repeated `lower_bound`s - which is massively faster than repeated `std::set` `lower_bound`s as it's more cache friendly).

Comment: *"By sorting the data and then using lower-bound would cost O(nLogn) instead of O(n) if directly the unsorted data is used."* - the risk of needing to do that is why a saner algo implementation that needed but couldn't rely on sorted input would do one pass to check for out-of-order elements before starting on the O(NlogN) sort.  In other words, my answer's focused on the best-case performance degrading to at least O(N); it may certainly be worse - at least O(NlogN) - if the actual input is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

These algorithms say:

> If you have sorted data, we'll perform some actions for you, quite efficiently.

Just like a ordinary binary search function you'd implement would expect the data to be sorted, these functions do expect data to be sorted. If you don't have data sorted, don't use them.

Just like you don't expect `sort` to insert elements for you, you shouldn't expect these algorithms to sort items for you.